# How to purge expired items from cache?

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I've got a nice little class built that acts as a cache. Each item has an expiration TimeSpan or DateTime. Each time an attempt to access an item in the cache is made, the item's expiration is checked, and if it's expired, the item is removed from the cache and nothing is returned.

That's great for objects that are accessed frequently, but if an item is put in the cache and never accessed again, it's never removed, even though it's expired.

What's a good methodology for expiring such items from the cache?

Should I have a background thread infinitely enumerating every item in the cache to check if it's expired?

Comment: Is this a fixed size cache? If so, I see no problems leaving items in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, maintaining a custom caching mechanism became more trouble than it was worth. There are several libraries out there that have already solved these problems. I would suggest using one of them. A popular one in .Net is the Enterprise Library, although I have limited experience with its caching abilities.

If you must use a custom caching mechanism, then I see no problem with a watchful thread idea you suggested. That is, if your application is a server-based application and not a web app. If it's a web app, you already have built in sliding expiration. You can then just wrap it in a strongly typed wrapper to avoid referencing cache items by key each time.

Answer (score 5):

The best code is no code.  Use the ASP.NET cache instead.  You can reference it as System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache in any application, not just web applications.

Comment: What if an assembly uses the HttpRuntime.Cache in two seperate places? They share the same cache, right? In that case, that won't work, unfortunately. It's already being used and I therefore cannot guarantee my items will not be removed.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  There is a single HttpRuntime.Cache object per AppDomain.  If you insert items in the cache in two different places, you should use different keys - this is true with any solution.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: A current alternative, if you can use the 4.0 framework, is the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx).  This breaks the dependency on ASP.Net and you may have multiple instances, but requires the full 4.0 framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an LRU (Least Recently Used) strategy, keep your items sorted by access time, when a new item is inserted into the cache **and** the cache is full you evicted the item that is last in that list. See [Cache algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms) at Wikipedia.

If you want to expire immediately, i would still only do that when things are accessed. I.e. when the cache object is accessed and it's time has expired refetch it.

Answer (score 1):

You could also on any change to the cache (re-)start a Timer with the Interval set to the closest expiry timestamp. This will not be accurate to milliseconds and depend on a message pump running, but is not very resource-demanding.

Harald Scheirich's answer is better though, if you don't mind that objects are hanging around forever, when the cache is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could clear suitably old items out of the cache on the first access after 1 minute after the last time items were cleared.

```
private DateTime nextFlush;
public object getItem(object key)
{
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now
  if (now > nextFlush)
  {
    Flush();
    nextFlush = now.AddMinutes(1)
  }
  return fetchItem(key);
}
```